# How to use slice and count in the same query in MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-repositories

**I need to combine slice and count in the same query, let me explain how:**

I have a collection which stores comments with his replies within in an array

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6b14796ede6d5169ad68a7"),
    "_class" : "com.social.model.comment.FirstLevelComment",
    "contentId" : "5a12996de7e84e0001b93a91",
    "replies" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6b151a6ede6d5169ad68b1"),
            "date" : ISODate("2018-01-26T11:46:34.202Z"),
            "text" : "Reply 1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6b151d6ede6d5169ad68b2"),
            "date" : ISODate("2018-01-26T11:46:37.357Z"),
            "text" : "Reply 2"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6b15206ede6d5169ad68b3"),
            "date" : ISODate("2018-01-26T11:46:40.170Z"),
            "text" : "Reply 3"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6b15236ede6d5169ad68b4"),
            "date" : ISODate("2018-01-26T11:46:43.025Z"),
            "text" : "Reply 4"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6b15256ede6d5169ad68b5"),
            "date" : ISODate("2018-01-26T11:46:45.931Z"),
            "text" : "Reply 5"
        }
    ],
    "date" : ISODate("2018-01-26T11:43:53.578Z"),
    "text" : "This is the comment text"
}
```

Every First level comment is stored in a separate document, so to retrieve all comments belong to a content, I have to make a query matching by "contentId" field.

But, I only want to retrieve the first two replies of every comment, so I have to use the $slice operator.

**But I have to retrieve too, the total amount of replies that a comment has, so can I do that in the same query?**

I'm using spring boot with mongo repositories, so for now my query is like this

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "{ replies : { $slice : 2 }}")
public Page<FirstLevelComment> findByContentId(String contentId, Pageable page);
```

But don't know how to add the number of replies to that query.

**EDIT**:
Added query as Alex P. said

```
db.comment.aggregate([
{$match:{contentId: "5a12996de7e84e0001b93a91"}},
{
  $project: { 
    _id: 1,
    _class: 1,
    contentId: 1,
    date: 1,
    text: 1,
    countSize: {$size: "$replies"},
    sl: {$slice: ["$replies", 2]}
  }
}])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB with Mongoose limit subdocuments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685297/mongodb-with-mongoose-limit-subdocuments)

Comment: You don't seem to have done much research on this...

Comment: not the same, I already successfully used slice, but I want to add the total number of elements

Comment: you want to retrieve only the first two comment ids' or you want to retrieve the comments from the id's also

Comment: I want to retrieve only the first two **replies** and the total number of them

Comment: You cant retrieve the total AND project only the 2 first. You'd have to use aggregation framework

Comment: any hint on how use the aggregation framework? I'm pretty new with mongodb

Comment: Are to sure your contentId is string not ObjectId like id ? Can you query with  ObjectId(hash) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd directly aggregate on your mongo server you would have to do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $project: { 
    _id: 1,
    _class: 1,
    contentId: 1,
    date: 1,
    text: 1,
    countSize: {$size: "$replies"},
    sl: {$slice: ["$replies", 2]}
  }
}
])
```

When using aggregation framework in your Java application with Spring Data you can't use `MongoRepository`. You would have to use `MongoTemplate` instead.
Have a look in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation) for more details

Comment: Thanks, seems to work fine for one element, but If I add $match:{contentId: "5a12996de7e84e0001b93a91"} to retrieve all comments for that contant, it shows nothing

Comment: @AciD don't know exactly what you've done unless you update your question with your `$match` query

Comment: Thanks anyway. I finally ended making a big one query and truncate with java

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation using `MongoTemplate`.

```
ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project().and("replies").slice(2).as("first 2 comments").and("replies").size().as("count");
SkipOperation skip  = Aggregation.skip(2L);
LimitOperation limit = Aggregation.limit(5);
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, skip, limit);
AggregationResults<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionname, Document.class);
```